# Best Practice for forking jsCodeLocation based on environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, xcodebuild

I want to be able to run my React-Native app locally or on the app store.

At present I have two lines:

```
//  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Which I comment or uncomment as appropriate. Would it be possible to do something like `if process.end.NODE_ENV === production` (except appropriate to Objective C/iOS) so as to actually fork this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Project-> Select "Build Settings" -> Search for "Preprocessor Macros" -> Define macro like STATE_DEVELOPMENT = 0 or 1.

In Release section define STATE_DEVELOPMENT = 0 and in Debug section define STATE_DEVELOPMENT = 1.

```
#if STATE_DEVELOPMENT
        jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
        jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

Comment: Can't this be implemented into react-native? You have a very good PR possibility here.